# Pandas: Rolling sum of a counter that resets

Tags: python, pandas

When collecting network traffic stats from a server it comes in as an increasing counter that resets at a certain point.  Lets say the data points for a certain time range look like

```
7
15
22
29     <--- reset happens next
2
5
7
20
25     <--- reset happens again
3
7
```

The total should be (29-7) + 25 + 7 = 54.

The actual data I have includes a hostname, e.g.

```
host1  5
host2 19
host1 7
host2 29
host1 9
host2 3
```

If I have that data in a pandas dataframe, how can I build the rolling sum and take the counter reset into consideration?

FWIW the counter resets around 10^12 so I'm not concerned about the lost data between reset and the next measurement point.

Comment: Are you meaning that the host and timestamp are part of an individual column? If so you can use regex to get the timestamp out, then do something similar to what mozway has done.

Comment: I've abstracted away the host and timestamp.  The thing I really want is
```
if current_row < previous_row:
  current_row
else:
  current_row - previous_row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mask to identify the restarts, sum them then subtract the first value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [7,15,22,29,2,5,7,20,25,3,7]})

out = (df.loc[df['value'].diff(-1).fillna(1).gt(0), 'value'].sum()
       -df['value'].iloc[0]
      )
```

Output: `54`

##### same logic per group

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': list('aaaaaabbbbb'),
                   'value': [7,15,22,29,2,5,7,20,25,3,7]})

def total(g):
    return (g[g.diff(-1).fillna(1).gt(0)].sum()
           -g.iloc[0]
          )
    
out = df.groupby('group')['value'].agg(total)
```

Output:

```
group
a    27
b    25
dtype: int64
```

Break down:

```
   group  value
0      a      7   #  -7
1      a     15
2      a     22
3      a     29   # +29
4      a      2
5      a      5   #  +5 = 27

6      b      7   #  -7
7      b     20
8      b     25   # +25
9      b      3
10     b      7   #  +7 = 25
```

Intermediates:

```
   group  value  diff(-1)  fillna(1)  gt(0) iloc[0]
0      a      7      -8.0       -8.0  False       X
1      a     15      -7.0       -7.0  False        
2      a     22      -7.0       -7.0  False        
3      a     29      27.0       27.0   True        
4      a      2      -3.0       -3.0  False        
5      a      5       NaN        1.0   True        
6      b      7     -13.0      -13.0  False       X
7      b     20      -5.0       -5.0  False        
8      b     25      22.0       22.0   True        
9      b      3      -4.0       -4.0  False        
10     b      7       NaN        1.0   True
```

*NB. `g.diff(-1).fillna(1).gt(0)` can also be simplified to `~g.diff(-1).le(0)`.*

Comment: `fillna(1)` makes the **last** row per group `1`. See the intermediates in the latest version of my answer. I also added another approach which I like better `~g.diff(-1).le(0)`, which uses the fact that most comparisons with NaN are `False`.